# Serialization/Deserialization in C/C++ for union arrays

Tags: c++, c, serialization

What is the best way to serialize / deserialize union arrays with strings and basic integer?

For example, we want to serialize:

```
union val_u {
int i;
char *s;
}

void serialize(void *buffer, const char *format, const union val_u src[]);
void deserialize(union val_u dst[], const char *format, const void *buffer);
```

The arbitrary composition of the union arrays is denoted by
the contents of the format string: 'i' indicates an integer
while 's' indicates a string.
serialize() copies the contents of src with union member
types denoted by format as described above into buffer.
deserialize() copies the contents of buffer into dst with
union member types denoted by format. It is literally the
reverse of the serialize() function.

format is just a string for identification (arbitrary)

Any idea how to implement the functions? Also, how to make it portable across architecture?

thanks!

Comment: sounds awfully like an assignment. what did you try? what is it that you don't understand in the assigment? what is C/C++?

Comment: I am going to vote to close, but just give the hint that serializing `char *` will be a pointer to data that you wont care about when you deserialize so you will have to deal with the string.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to print everything out to its string representation.  Don't do any binary representations and you don't have to worry about representations or alignment or padding.

then just use the string to integer functions (atoi and the like) to get them back into numeric representations in the deserialization routines.

It's not the most efficient way to do things, but that's not normally the most important thing.  Just getting things right, first, is most important.  Then, if it's not good enough, worry about improving it.

```
iThis is a string
n234234
n8292
iMore Stuff
n-92
```

I think this is what you were saying, and it should work well for you.